# ieframe.dll cannot do Web Authentication

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

Some applications in Microsoft Windows, use a DLL named `ieframe.dll` for some browsing actions (like IE).
This file is in `%SystemRoot%/System32/ieframe.dll`.

Some applications need Web Authentication (for example *Team Foundation Server* and *Google Drive For Windows*, ...).

The problem is when these application start authenticating from web server, it shows just an empty white screen.

I use Windows 7 (x86) Service Pack 1.

How can I fix this DLL ?

Comment: try to repair broken files with **sfc /scannow**

Comment: @magicandre1981 I try it, and the result was nothing about fix that DLL.

Comment: if the DLL is fine, the issue is somewhere else. Reset the IE options.